# Sqlite: Insert or Update table with information from another table

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I am new to sqlite and am creating a Discord trivia bot that has a leader board that tracks the number of correct answers per user.  I am not sure how to either add a new row for when someone new gets a question correct or update a row when another person that has already gotten an answer correct answers one correctly.  Code the that I have below only updates the leader board table for the first userId in the answers table.  But there could be multiple users in the answers table that could get the question right.

I am using the libraries discord.js and sqlite.

The descriptions of the tables are below:

The user's answer is tracked in a table called answers.  The table answers has the attributes userId and answer.  The userId is the id of the user that gave an answer and answer is the choice the user.

There is another table called leaderboards that tracks the number of correct answers each user has.  The attributes of table leaderboards are userId and number.  The userId is the id of the user and number is the number of correct answers.

```
cAnswer = 'c';
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answer ="${cAnswer}"`).then(aRow => {
    if (aRow){
        sql.get(`SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE userId ="${aRow.userId}"`).then(lRow => {
            if (!lRow){
                sql.run("INSERT INTO leaderboard (userId, number) VALUES (?, ?)", [aRow.userId, 1]);
            }
            else{
                num = lRow.number + 1;
                sql.run(`UPDATE leaderboard SET number = ${num} WHERE userId = ${aRow.userId}`);
            }
            const user = client.users.get(aRow.userId);
            user.send("You answered the jeep trivia question correctly!\nThe correct answer was *" + cAnswer + "*.");
        }).catch(() => {
            console.error;
            sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leaderboard (userId TEXT, number INT)").then(() => {
                sql.run("INSERT INTO leaderboard (userId, number) VALUES (?, ?)", [aRow.userId, 1]);
            });
            const user = client.users.get(aRow.userId);
            user.send("You answered the jeep trivia question correctly!\nThe correct answer was *" + cAnswer + "*.");
        });
    }

}).catch(() => {
    console.error;
});
```

Comment: Do your `console.error` statements work? I think you should be doing something like this in each `.catch()` statement:
`.catch(err => {   console.error(err);  });`

Answer (score 1):

I think that having 2 answer columns in separate tables is contrary to normalisation and that a single answer column could suffice and would simplify your issue.

For example assume that we have a questions/problems table defined as :-

```
CREATE TABLE problems (problemid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, problem TEXT, answer TEXT)
```

- Which for the example is populated as with 2 questions, as per :-
  [image]

There is a users table defined as :-

```
CREATE TABLE users (userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT)
```

- Which is populated with 3 users as :-
  [image]

Lastly there is an answers table defined as :-

```
CREATE TABLE answers (userref INTEGER, problemref INTEGER, answer INTEGER DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY (userref, problemref))
```

- Which is populated with some answers (noting that the answer column will contain 0 for an incorrect answer and 1 for a correct answer), the userref column references the respective user, the problemref column references the respective problem :-

[image]

- So the first row is saying that user 1 (Fred) incorrectly answered problem 1.
- The 2nd row is saying that Fred answered problem 2 correctly.
- 3rd that Bert answered problem 2 incorrectly.
- 4th that Tom answered problem 2 correctly.

The following query would produce a leaderboard :-

```
SELECT username||' got '||sum(answers.answer)||' correct.' AS number_correct
FROM answers 
    JOIN users ON userref = userid
GROUP BY userref ORDER BY sum(answers.answer) DESC
```

and would look like :-

[image]

You then only have 1 column to maintain. You just have to insert the row (if you want to cater for reattempts then check if insert was not ok then update the row).